# Flag a region to not be affected by the auto formatting rules

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, autoformatting

I'm looking for a way to keep a region of my to code have a certain number of tab indents.
The tabs are representing a relation to the field above it.

I.e.

```
public string Foo1
    pubic string F1Bar1
public string Foo2
public string Foo3
    public string F3Bar1
    public string F3Bar2
        public string F3B2Foobar1
public string Foo4
```

Running an auto format would of course align all these string, Is there a way to flag this part of code to be neglected by the auto formatter. keeping the indents while the rest of the code does get formatted?

(Resharper is Available for me)

Comment: I will simply go ahead and say that there's (probably) no way to ignore a part of the code, to prevent it from being automatically formatted, even with ReSharper.

Instead of asking you *why* would you want to do it, I would like to suggest wrapping your field "hierarchy" in appropriate types. Those fields must represent some logical structure, why not make it one?

Comment: We're creating a data table which will be used by a third party.
The table exits of several of our own database tables, To keep track of where our own columns are  coming from, i would like to use the described notation.
I agree with your statement, Question remains out of interest and a  bit of laziness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do it in ReSharper 7.0 or earlier. But you can vote for this feature here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-9997 .

Answer (score 0):

You could add a **newline after `public`** and indent before `string`, i.e.:

```
    public
      string F1Bar1;
```

This format would not be changed, at least on my installation/settings (R# 5.1.3, VS 2010).

Unfortunatly this helps for **second level only**. It's not possible for third or more levels.